# How to set value for missing field in range aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm grouping by `offerId`, the each bucket has two buckets: `price <=0` and `price > 0`. I need to make sure that `price <= 0` includes documents where `price` field is missing:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "by_offer_id": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "offerId"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "by_price": {
               "range": {
                  "field": "price",
                  "ranges": [
                     {
                        "to": 0
                     },
                     {
                        "from": 0
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "price_stats": {
                     "stats": {
                        "field": "price"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I've tried adding `"missing": 0` after `"field": "price",`, but it throws `SearchPhaseExecutionException`.

I'm using `1.7.5`, but potentially could use syntax from `2.4.x`.

Comment: You need to put `"missing": 0` inside the `stats` aggregation not the `range` one. But `missing` was not available in ES 1.7, you need ES 2.0 at least.

Comment: @Val Looks like it''s not supported on 1.7 but I'll definitely try on 2.4

Comment: Perhaps it's possible to use sub aggregation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-bucket-missing-aggregation.html ?

Comment: Yes, but you won't get the result inside your range aggregation result

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case I don't event need to set `"missing" : 0`,

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "by_offer_id": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "offerId"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "price_stats": {
               "stats": {
                  "field": "price"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

because term aggregation returns `total` document count, white `stats` aggregation only includes documents with existing price and returns the total number. I can deduce how many document don't have a price field by subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should use script just like this:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_offer_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "offerId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_price": {
          "range": {
            "script": {
              "lang": "painless",
              "source": "doc['price'].value ==null ? 0 : doc['price'].value"
            },
            "ranges": [
              {
                "to": 0
              },
              {
                "from": 0
              }
            ]
          },
          "aggs": {
            "price_stats": {
              "stats": {
                "field": "price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
"source": "doc['price'].value * 1"
```